# Exclude step from gradle build for specific test classes

Tags: docker, gradle, conditional-statements, step

I'm new to gradle, and I'm sure that this can be done somehow, but I can't figure out how - project does use *dockerCompose* task. It's spinning some docker dependencies up for tests. The problem is, it done in very dummy way:

`dockerCompose.isRequiredBy( test )`

which means that every single time I run tests from IDE, even if I'm running single unit test, that does not need docker dependencies at all, it's still starting up some docker containers(or failing miserably if docker agent is down).

I would like to run *dockerCompose* step **only** for some tests, only the ones that really need it. I don't have full conception, how I would like to mark those tests, but probably the easiest and most readable solution would be to use name, let's say ***DockerTest or ***IntegrationTest. And only for those ones I would run *dockerCompose* step.

I tried few different approaches, f.e. using system property in test's *Before* method and *if statement* in build.gradle(but it's already too late, *dockerCompose* already started before we went to *test* step), I've tried registering new task that extends *Test* and then to use 'filter' command, but it does not seem to work either(the task is started regardless from the test name, so it does not help me at all).

What would be the best way to do it, if that's even possible?